# Using external fonts in a Java Applet

Tags: java, fonts, applet, truetype

Is it possible to use a font not on the user's machine for text displayed in a java applet.
Like linking to a ttf font file in the same location as the java applet almost in an @fontface fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Font.createFont`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) with `fontFormat` [`TRUETYPE_FONT`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#TRUETYPE_FONT):

```
Font f = Font.createFont( Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("font.ttf") );
```

---

As also described in [Sun-Tutorial Working with Text APIs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html) the returned font size is `1 pt`, you can change this afterwards:

```
f = font.deriveFont(12f);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But if I have it on a server I get FilePermissionException read error when it tries to access the font file.
Serverside the code and font file have read and execute permissions. What do I have to do to grant my code access to the font file?

Comment: @Jaxsun: Try to put the font file into your jar-file if possible, that should solve permission problems. If that's not an option, consider asking another question.